# batch file copy contents of 1 file into another

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I am trying to create a bat file to copy the contents of one file and append it to the end of another file.

Say I have a file named **test.txt** and I want to append the contents of test.txt to a file that is already created with the name of **results.txt**

How can this be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do `type test.txt >> results.txt`

Also see [this reference at ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for redirection.

Note that `TYPE`  will convert Unicode files to ANSI. If you need to keep files as they are, download the UnxUtils and use `cat` instead of `type`.

Comment: Side note (not relevant to this particular question, but if someone looks with a related problem): For binary files you probably want to to `copy` to concatenate both.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to use the "copy" command (you can use it within your batch file), it'll do ascii or binary mode, alloows for appending.

> Copies one or more files to another location.
>
> COPY [/D] [/V] [/N] [/Y | /-Y] [/Z] [/A | /B ] source [/A | /B]
>        [+ source [/A | /B] [+ ...]] [destination [/A | /B]]
>
> source       Specifies the file or files to be copied.   /A
>   Indicates an ASCII text file.   /B           Indicates a binary file. 
>   /D           Allow the destination file to be created decrypted
>   destination  Specifies the directory and/or filename for the new
>   file(s).   /V           Verifies that new files are written correctly.
>   /N           Uses short filename, if available, when copying a file
>   with a
>                  non-8dot3 name.   /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
>                  existing destination file.   /-Y          Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
>                  existing destination file.   /Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.
>
> The switch /Y may be preset in the COPYCMD environment variable. This
>   may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is to prompt
>   on overwrites unless COPY command is being executed from within a
>   batch script.
>
> **To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).**

So, to append file1 to file2 and call it newfile the command would be

```
copy file1+file2 newfile
```

To just append file2 to file1 the command should be

```
copy file1+file2 file1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
type test.txt >> results.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

*type test.txt > results.txt*
to replace the content of "result.txt" with the content of "test.txt"

*type test.txt >> results.txt*
to add the content of "test.txt" after the content of "result.txt"